# Binding menu control to XmlDataProvider from code behind

Tags: .net, wpf, menu, menuitem

I have an XML file which has menu/menuitem tags similar to what we get when we create a menu in [XAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Application_Markup_Language). I am using binding object and then setting the binding source to [XmlDataProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.xmldataprovider.aspx). I just want to have menu control on the XAML. The rest of it should be done from code behind. (for example, `<menu name=menu1>` in XAML). I want to do the binding in code behind.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new binding, set its source and use [`SetBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598273.aspx) on the menu to bind a property.

```
var binding = new Binding();
binding.Source = myXmlDataProvider;
menu1.SetBinding(Menu.DataContextProperty, binding);
```

What property you bind to is up to you, I would first bind the [`DataContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext.aspx) and then bind relative to that on other properties such as [`ItemsSources`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource.aspx).

Comment: @Peter Mortensen: If i talk about some property the link should in my opinion go to the official documentation of said property and not some random forum thread or blog post. Also you linked to the wrong `DataContext` property, please be careful with such edits.